# how split or tokenize Arabic text into sentences in python

Tags: python

My question i need to split or tokenize the Arabic text into sentences, which is every sentences end with (.), then tokenization into word. and the output as you see bellow. how can i fix it.

```
text = """ طوقت الشرطة المكان، عقب انتهاء الوقت المحدد لهم بالمغادرة. وكان المهاجرون يسعون إلى   الوصول إلى بريطانيا، ويقولون إنه ليس أمامهم مكان آخر ليذهبوا إليه، بعد تدمير المخيمات. وكانت عدة حافلات تقل عشرات من أفراد الشرطة قد وصلت صباح الأربعاء إلى المخيمات. وتشارك الشرطة الآن في المواجهة مع النشطاء هناك، بحسب ما ذكره مراسل بي بي سي، بول آدمز، الموجود في المكان."""
posttext = text.decode('utf-8')
sentences = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(posttext)
print sentences


the output is :
[u'\u0637\u0648\u0642\u062a', u'\u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0637\u0629', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'\u060c', u'\u0639\u0642\u0628', u'\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0647\u0627\u0621', u'\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0642\u062a', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u062f\u062f', u'\u0644\u0647\u0645', u'\u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645\u063a\u0627\u062f\u0631\u0629', u'.', u'\u0648\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0647\u0627\u062c\u0631\u0648\u0646', u'\u064a\u0633\u0639\u0648\u0646', u'\u0625\u0644\u0649', u'\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0635\u0648\u0644', u'\u0625\u0644\u0649', u'\u0628\u0631\u064a\u0637\u0627\u0646\u064a\u0627', u'\u060c', u'\u0648\u064a\u0642\u0648\u0644\u0648\u0646', u'\u0625\u0646\u0647', u'\u0644\u064a\u0633', u'\u0623\u0645\u0627\u0645\u0647\u0645', u'\u0645\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'\u0622\u062e\u0631', u'\u0644\u064a\u0630\u0647\u0628\u0648\u0627', u'\u0625\u0644\u064a\u0647', u'\u060c', u'\u0628\u0639\u062f', u'\u062a\u062f\u0645\u064a\u0631', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062e\u064a\u0645\u0627\u062a', u'.', u'\u0648\u0643\u0627\u0646\u062a', u'\u0639\u062f\u0629', u'\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0644\u0627\u062a', u'\u062a\u0642\u0644', u'\u0639\u0634\u0631\u0627\u062a', u'\u0645\u0646', u'\u0623\u0641\u0631\u0627\u062f', u'\u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0637\u0629', u'\u0642\u062f', u'\u0648\u0635\u0644\u062a', u'\u0635\u0628\u0627\u062d', u'\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0628\u0639\u0627\u0621', u'\u0625\u0644\u0649', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062e\u064a\u0645\u0627\u062a', u'.', u'\u0648\u062a\u0634\u0627\u0631\u0643', u'\u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0637\u0629', u'\u0627\u0644\u0622\u0646', u'\u0641\u064a', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u062c\u0647\u0629', u'\u0645\u0639', u'\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0634\u0637\u0627\u0621', u'\u0647\u0646\u0627\u0643', u'\u060c', u'\u0628\u062d\u0633\u0628', u'\u0645\u0627', u'\u0630\u0643\u0631\u0647', u'\u0645\u0631\u0627\u0633\u0644', u'\u0628\u064a', u'\u0628\u064a', u'\u0633\u064a', u'\u060c', u'\u0628\u0648\u0644', u'\u0622\u062f\u0645\u0632', u'\u060c', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f', u'\u0641\u064a', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'.']
```

Comment: do you want to print the output in Arabic or translate it?
Whenever you print sentences it's still in utf-8 which is why you \u0637.... you'll have to change that to whatever the code for Arabic is.
Something like;
For i in sentences:
    print i.decode('Arabiccode')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
text = " وقت الشرطة المكان، عقب انتهاء الوقت المحدد لهم بالمغادرة. وكان المهاجرون يسعون لى   الوصول إلى بريطانيا، ويقولون إنه ليس أمامهم مكان آخر ليذهبوا إليه، بعد تدمير المخيمات. وكانت عدة حافلات تقل عشرات من أفراد الشرطة قد وصلت صباح الأربعاء إلى المخيمات. وتشارك الشرطة الآن في المواجهة مع النشطاء هناك، بحسب ما ذكره مراسل بي بي سي، بول آدمز، الموجود في المكان."
posttext = text.decode('utf-8')

sentences = text.split(".")
for sentence in sentences:
    print sentence
```

Comment: A dot doesn't mean the end of the sentence. It could be an abbreviation, part of a number, etc. And what about other sentence boundaries like question/exclamation marks and many other possibilities I might miss because I'm not a linguist and don't know anything about arabic. So I consider this answer not right.

Comment: @DavidVartanian The author explicitly mentioned (.) as sentence separator. Furthermore, the arabic language uses (٫) (in hex U+066B) as decimal separator and (٬) as the thousands separator ([read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)). So I guess *"I might miss because I'm not a linguist and don't know anything about arabic"* may not be enough for a downvote.

Comment: Is a normal ASCII dot (.) a sentence boundary in Arabic?

Comment: The period at the end of a sentence in Arabic is the same ASCII dot, but the problem is that the question mark and exclamation mark would not be caught by this. Maybe OP is working with a very limited data set (looks like a news article here) and he knows for sure that the period is the only separator, so this would work fine for them, but it's not a good general solution.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `nltk.sent_tokenize(text)` like so:

```
>>> text = """ طوقت الشرطة المكان، عقب انتهاء الوقت المحدد لهم بالمغادرة. وكان المهاجرون يسعون إلى   الوصول إلى بريطانيا، ويقولون إنه ليس أمامهم مكان آخر ليذهبوا إليه، بعد تدمير المخيمات. وكانت عدة حافلات تقل عشرات من أفراد الشرطة قد وصلت صباح الأربعاء إلى المخيمات. وتشارك الشرطة الآن في المواجهة مع النشطاء هناك، بحسب ما ذكره مراسل بي بي سي، بول آدمز، الموجود في المكان."""
>>> text = re.sub("؟", "?", text) # replace any ؟ with ?
>>> for sen in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
...     print(sen)
 طوقت الشرطة المكان، عقب انتهاء الوقت المحدد لهم بالمغادرة.
وكان المهاجرون يسعون إلى   الوصول إلى بريطانيا، ويقولون إنه ليس أمامهم مكان آخر ليذهبوا إليه، بعد تدمير المخيمات.
وكانت عدة حافلات تقل عشرات من أفراد الشرطة قد وصلت صباح الأربعاء إلى المخيمات.
وتشارك الشرطة الآن في المواجهة مع النشطاء هناك، بحسب ما ذكره مراسل بي بي سي، بول آدمز، الموجود في المكان.
```

We have replaced "؟" with "?" because `nltk.sent_tokenize()` works only on English.

### Side Note

Sentence tokenization is different than what you describe. For example, assume the following sentence:

```
ا.د. مجدي يعقوب من أعظم الأطباء الجراحين بالعالم
```

When applying what you have suggested (to split the text based on .), then the acronym "ا.د" will be split which could cause unpredicted results. Also, . isn't the only delimiter that splits sentences... there are also ! and ?